# Splitting background horizontally in half (with different colors) in Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to split the background of a **full-width** row 50/50 while using Foundation's grid system? Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Screenshot of desired layout]

This is a simple exercise, when not using Foundation's grid system. For example, you could use the following CSS with two divs with id's `#blue` and `#black`:

```
#blue{
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%
    height:100%;
    color:black;
}
#black{
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    width:50%
    height:100%;
    color:white;
}
```

However, I'm having a difficult time achieving this, while retaining page padding that aligns with the rest of the row padding on my page.

Is there an easy way to do this while remaining within the Foundation grid system? Right now, it's seeming as if I'm going to have to break out of the framework and do a whole bunch of formatting and media queries to ensure that everything aligns with the rest of my content. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CSS background gradient on the body. And remove it for the small media query.

```
body {

  background: linear-gradient(left, #b3ddc5 49%,#333333 49%,#333333 `100%);

}
```

The result would be something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/4wM4Q/)**

Comment: There are a couple issues with your code, but it definitely got me where I needed to be. Thanks for a quality answer. Here's the updated code: `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #b2dcc6, #b2dcc6 49%, #333333 49%);`

Comment: You'll want to use the browser-prefixed version for sure. Mine was tailored to my browser and I didn't test it in others, unfortunately. Glad it helped though.

Answer (score 5):

Brett's answer did it. I made some minor corrections to his answer and tailored it to my use case. In the end, my colored section looked similar to the following:

```
#section {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #b2dcc6, #b2dcc6 49%, #333333 49%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #b2dcc6, #b2dcc6 49%, #333333 49%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {

    #section > .row > .columns:first-child {
        background-color: #b2dcc6;
    }

    #section > .row > .columns:last-child {
        background-color: #333333;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margins on your elements wrapper, and compensate with padding.